# Error With Chartboost (Undefined symbols for architecture _crypto_sign)

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocos2d-iphone, chartboost

I have got some linker errors while building my client app which is not developed by me. But I still solved many build errors and linker errors for other third party errors.

When I added chartboost to the project I got these errors which I have attached in a screenshot.
[image]

Can anyone solve this issue?

This is build target settings

[image]

And I have only one target which is Candyman